# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle default 'register' route is "/"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I've got FOSUserBundle 1.3 set up on Symfony 2.8. When I go to /register I get a 'Route Not Found' error. I did some digging, and the `app/console debug:router` command shows that the `fos_user_registration_register` route is set to '/'. This doesn't seem right. Am I missing something? How do I access the default registration form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow when I copied over the routing.yml file, I had excluded all the `prefix:` options in the routes. I had to add the `prefix: \register` option below the registration route.

See the Symfony documentation on[Prefixing Imported Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the below `config.yml`

```
fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register
```

You can take a look for advance routing configuration :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/routing.html